# Clearing cache via admin_toolbar results in white screen with "Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default"

Tags: redirection

[image: Flush all caches]

After pressing this admin_tool button to Flush all caches, the browser hangs on a white screen with the message: `Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it`. The hung URL is `/admin/flush?token=wieu87APDL`

- This only happens on production, not local
- Clearing cache in `/admin/config/development/performance` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no doubt the admin_toolbar contributed module. Looking at [a bug report to the issue that is identical to this question](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar/issues/3114229) it is likely that there is a caching proxy with this website and that Drupal is not set up [to trust the IP addresses of that proxy](https://www.drupal.org/node/425990).

Comment: More than this cannot be said without more information in the question.

Comment: I had visited that link earlier, and we made some reverse proxy changes which fixed other redirects but not this one. I applied the patch (not the one currently in green, which has a typo `TrustedTrusted[...]` and the problem was fixed right up. Thanks cilefen!